# Create objects from a list of IDs in a simple way

Tags: java, list, object, mapping, ids

Is there a way to simplify the following with a stream or something?

```java
final List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>(fruitIds.size());
for (final long id : fruitIds) {
   final var fruit = new Fruit();
   fruit.setId(id);

   fruits.add(fruit);
}
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is it ok to modify `Fruit` so you can pass the `id` as an argument to the constructor?

Comment: If Fruit takes id as a constructor parameter: `List<Fruit> fruits = Arrays.stream(fruitIds).mapToObj(i -> new Fruit(i)).toList();`

Comment: Although I'm not sure how  this simplifies anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a constructor would be optimal.  This assumes an int id.

```
class Fruit {
    int id;
   
    public Fruit(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

for (Fruit id : fruitIds) {
    Fruits.add(new Fruit(id));
}
```

But if you aren't allowed to modify your `Fruit class` creating another class to act as a Factory class would work.
Again I am presuming `id` is an `int`.

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>(fruitIds.size());

for (final var id : fruitIds) {
    fruits.add(FruitFactory.instance(id));
}

class FruitFactory {
    public static Fruit instance(int id) {
        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
        fruit.setId(id);
        return fruit;
    }
}
```

If you are only creating instances of Fruit in a single place in your code then the above would be of little use.  In that case I would just stick with what you have.

Using the above, the stream solution would be

```
List<Fruit> fruits = 
     fruitIds.stream().map(FruitFactory::instance).toList();
```

And with a constructor

```
List<Fruit> fruits = fruitIds.stream().map(Fruit::new).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do agree with all of you that just modifying the constructor or adding a new one with just the ID is the easiest way. Thank you for the thorough answer!